# Why is this "Not an answer" flag disputed?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I was doing [a review](https://gis.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/82710) recently on an answer. I got the impression that the answer basically is along the lines of,

> I am working [on somethings] ..., now I am trying to edit data and it
>   [ArcSDE] is not letting me ... Can I delete them. Thanks.

I thought this is a question and "Not an answer", and marked the post as so, but my flag was just disputed.

I was wondering if I am missing something here about the flagging?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect that the reviewer (not me) on this one must have hit the wrong button because to me it looks like your flag falls well within what Robert Harvey says in [his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198008/not-an-answer-flag-declined-dont-see-why/198010#198010) to [Not An Answer Flag Declined - Don't See Why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198008/not-an-answer-flag-declined-dont-see-why):

> For "Not an Answer" flags, we're looking for questions posted as
>   answers, comments posted as answers, "thanks," things like that.

When it was flagged again as Not An Answer, I marked it as Helpful and the "answer" was deleted.