# Do disputed flags ever become resolved?

Tags: support, status-completed, review-queues, flagging

I currently have three disputed flags listed in my flagging history. I tried looking for other possible questions they may have answered however, I only came across [Why is this "Not an answer" flag disputed?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4208) which didn't seem to cover what I'm looking for.

[image]

These three are from early to mid 2016, do they ever become resolved or do they remain disputed?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the following Meta Stack Exchange posts:

- [What is a disputed flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag)
- [What is the difference between disputed and declined flags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141292/what-is-the-difference-between-disputed-and-declined-flags)

From the last post:

> Disputed flag: When you flag an answer as NAA or VLQ and the post doesn't result in deletion but someone recommended deletion, the flag is disputed. Spam and offensive flags on post that are rolled back are also disputed.

The answer to your question is: 'they remain disputed'.